# Excluding an element from a predefined set in GAMS ?

Tags: gams-math

Over a predefined set S /s1*s100/ I need to write something like this 
M_s - M_shat =g= 0 , where (shat) is any other element in the set (S) except the element (s).
How can I do that in GAMS?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an alias set and a conditional with the SameAs operator.

```
Alias(S,SS);
E_M(s,ss)$(not SameAs(s,ss)).. M(s) - M(ss) =G= 0;
```

Comment: Thanks  @Martin  for your prompt reply, I'm new in GAMS that is why sometimes I miss such that basic ideas .... Thanks again